# How to create summary sheet like html tables

Tags: html, css

I am working with HTML tables and need to achieve like attached image.

[image]

When I try to achieve this,I caught problem like this

①  I couldn't figure out how not to display border line.

②  Each cell size is not aligned compared to desired result.

I would like to achieve in a certain way. If you have any opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

```css
table {
border-collapse:collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;}

td {
border:solid black 1px;
}

.noborder {
}

.noborder2{
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="noborder">Total (summary)</td>
      <td class="noborder"></td>
      <td class="noborder"></td>
      <td class="noborder"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td class="noborder2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: have a look at colspan and rowspan  attribute https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using `empty-cells: hide;`.

> Note: but the border is bit off since it removes the td border where the content doesn't exists. If that's ok.

```css
.tbl {
  empty-cells: hide;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

td {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table class="tbl" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="noborder">Total (summary)</td>
      <td class="noborder"></td>
      <td class="noborder"></td>
      <td class="noborder"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td class="noborder2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the another version:

```css
.MainDiv {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: inline-block;
}

table.tbl {
  empty-cells: hide;
}

td.noborder {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

td.removeBorder {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

td:empty {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
  <table class="tbl" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="removeBorder">Total (summary)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="noborder">A</td>
        <td class="noborder">B</td>
        <td class="noborder">C</td>
        <td class="noborder"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="noborder">1</td>
        <td class="noborder">2</td>
        <td class="noborder">3</td>
        <td class="noborder">6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering,Are there any way to align each cell width as attached image? Thanks

Comment: @Heisenberg I have updated my second snippet as you asked, let me know.